# How to model this problem with multiple objectives?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, multi-objective-optimization

This question is related to [How to deal this L0 norm of a vector of L2 or L1 norms in objective?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/9769/how-to-deal-this-l0-norm-of-a-vector-of-l2-or-l1-norms-in-objective)

I have an optimization variable denoted as ${\bf A\in\mathbb{C}^{100\times 5}}=\begin{bmatrix}{\bf a}_1&{\bf a}_2&{\bf a}_3&{\bf a}_4&{\bf a}_5\end{bmatrix}$.

Here, ${\bf a}_1$ is the 1st column of matrix ${\bf A}$, ${\bf a}_2$ is the 2nd column of matrix ${\bf A}$ and so on.

Let ${\bf b}=\begin{bmatrix}\|{\bf a}_1\|_2&\|{\bf a}_2\|_2&\|{\bf a}_3\|_2&\|{\bf a}_4\|_2&\|{\bf a}_5\|_2\end{bmatrix}$ be the vector of norms of all the column vectors in matrix ${\bf A}$.

$\textbf{I want to make the norms zero for as many columns as possible.}$. Please see prof. Rubin's proposal.

At the same time I also want to minimize the $\|A\|_F$ or $\|A\|_2$.

How to model this objective?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways:

1. Scale up the smaller objective value so choose $\alpha_1 obj1_1 + \alpha_2obj_2 $ so that $\alpha_1 obj1 \ge \alpha_2obj_2 $. In your case try adding weight of 50 to the smaller objective.
2. Solve the problem with bigger objective value first, then while solving the next objective add a constraint using the solved optimal value. Like if z is optimal solution for max$\Vert A \Vert_2 $, then while solving for min $\Vert b_i \Vert_0$ (basically minimizing $\sum_i z_i$ where $\beta_i \le Mz_i$ with $b_i \le \beta_i$ & $-b_i \le \beta_i$ as in the previous post) add constraint $z \le \Vert A \Vert_2$ or whatever linear form you are using for $L_2$ norm.
3. Try with multiplicative relation like obj1*obj2. Then use log for the objective $\log Z = \log obj_1 + \log obj_2$. Then you have to transform back to actual optimal value using $\exp$ of log base.

Comment: You have one objective with max value 5. You can multiply that objective with a larger number like 50.